# Windowed Alt+Tab experience completely gone from Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, alt-tab

I started using Windows 11 this morning. After a couple of hours (and installed updates?), I don't know what happened or what I did, but my Alt+Tab menu reverted to some dully one that I remember from Windows XP:

[image]

I've been struggling with this for past two hours, browsing through Windows 11 settings and dozens of webpages. I've tried to enable / disable Aero, I've tried to use tricks for changing Windows 11 Alt+Tab experience back to Windows 10's, all for nothing.

Does anyone recognize this behaviour and can advice me on what is wrong and how to fix that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Windowed Alt+Tab experience completely gone from Windows 11

Windows 11 is quite different .

Alt Tab shows you a small Window of each active app. The entire desktop space is used and each app shows up in this space.

There is nothing wrong with your system with respect to this feature if you see the small app within the full desktop screen.

If you are seeing the old style Alt Tab (pre-Win 10) then there may be something wrong and you may have some legacy software installed. I cannot imagine how such a thing would happen. In this case, you may need to Repair Windows 11 as there may be some legacy software causing what you see.

Repair can be done from the Windows 11 Media Creation Link.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Comment: Are you trying to say that is normal behaviour? If so you are mistaken my friend.

Comment: For Windows 11, yes. What I posted is completely normal and native Windows behavior. Many changes in Win 11 from Win 10 and prior.

Comment: Have you not seen the standard Alt+Tab interface for W11? It looks absolutely nothing like that, there is something wrong with the installation.

Comment: Yes I have seen it, used it and I tried to describe it. Medium size window for each app on the total desktop. I made a further edit to my answer to help clarify,.  Snippy and Snagit do not capture it. But this is the new way Windows 11 works.

Answer (score 1):

To enable Windowed Alt+Tab interface in Windows 11:

- Download
  [ViveTool](https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe/releases/)
- Extract its files to a folder
- Open Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator
- Position to the ViveTool folder
- Run the following command :

  ```
  vivetool addconfig 36226836 2
  ```
- To disable Windowed Alt+Tab windowed and restore the Windows 11
  full-screen experience, use the following command:

  ```
  vivetool delconfig 36226836 2
  ```

Note that this change may be undone by Windows 11 after a few
reboots, so you will then need to redo the above.

For more information, see
[Windows 11 tests Windowed Alt+Tab experience, how to enable](https://techdows.com/2022/01/enable-windows-11-alt-tab-windowed.html).

Comment: I know the solution with ViveTool. You answer explains (in short) how to "bring Windows 10's Alt+Tab experience to Windows 11". This is not what I am asking about. I want to understand why the original, unchanged Windows 11's Alt+Tab experience was replaced in my case with this what I am showing at the screenshot. And how to get it back.

Comment: I can't know why this has changed, maybe a botched Windows Update. My answer describes how to enable both kinds of Alt+Tab displays using ViveTool, Windowed or not Windowed.